# why do switch statements run every case after the case that is entered?

Tags: java, syntax, switch-statement

I understand that switch statements will run all the code after the first true case, but why does it execute every case after the true case?

Answer (score -3):

You need to `break;` after executing the case code block if you do not want to check the other switch conditions after a matching condition is found.

Comment: Question isn't *how* to break it, but more like *why* do we need to break it?

Comment: The question is why does it continue executing the rest of the switch after finding a true case.

Comment: Yes, and does "You need to break; ..." answer it? Question is more about design decision about *why* switch-case work as it work, not *how* to use it.